# Permission denied when connecting to server Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I install Postgres9.5.1 via Homebrew. However, I am having problems creating a database by using "createdb". Originally the message said: "createdb: command not found". Then I uninstall and install Homebrew and updated Postgres.

However, now I am getting a new error:

```
 createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to      server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried a couple of things such as:

```
 $rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

which gave back:

"Permission denied"

Also:

```
 $postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
 postgres cannot access the server configuration file                "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

Or:

```
 $grep unix_socket /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
 grep: /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf: Permission denied
```

I don't know what to do, I don't really understand what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After dealing with this problem for days I finally managed to solve it by uninstalling and installing Postgresql via Homebrew and initiating the server. This is how I did it:

make sure Xcode (for Os X users) is up to date

```
  xcode-select --install
```

Install Homebrew

```
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

  brew doctor
  brew search
  brew install postgres
  brew update
```

Postgres should be install. Now, make sure you have the permissions required to use it, this is done by allowing your user such permission:

```
  sudo chown -R :admin /usr/local
```

The permission problem should be solved. Now you (as I did) could be facing a problem related to the server.

```
     psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost
```

This will do the trick:

```
     launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
     mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres-deletemewhenitsallgood
     initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
     launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

or

```
     rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

You can now start the database server using:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start
```

Don't forget to adapt this command lines to your specific case and addresses.

Good luck

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Success on macOS Sierra with PostgreSQL 9.6.1. I did one additional command to make my setup more similar to typical postgres: `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/createuser -s postgres`